# Convert string array to array with ascii codes

Tags: c, string, atoi

I'm trying to convert every character of a string to its ASCII code. The string array comes from stdin.

I'm trying to loop through the string and convert every character to ASCII with atoi() and add this ASCII code to a new int array.

```
char s2[1024];
fgets(s2, 1024, stdin);
int arr[1024]; 
int i = 0;
while (i < strlen(s2))
  {
  char * start = s2;
  int j = 0;
    while(start != "\0")
    {
      arr[j++] = atoi(start);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

I'm pretty new to C and I thought this could work, but I get an "segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I run the code. I know this error has to do something with the memory, but I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. The individual characters of your string are alread ASCII.

Comment: `char s2[] = {};` this isn't C, and even if the compiler tolerates it, it probably doesn't reserve any space.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a minimal example of your input and the exact content you expect to be in `arr`.

Comment: As a side note, you should never use `atoi`. Make a habit of using `strtol` instead - it is the same but safer and also works with more number bases than decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything because the characters in `s2` are already ASCII values.

You probably want something like this:

```
char s2[1024];
fgets(s2, 1024, stdin);
int arr[1024]; 
int i = 0;
while (i < strlen(s2))
{
  arr[i] = s2[i];
  i++;
}
```

If your input is say:

```
ABCD
```

`arr` will contain following values: `{65, 66, 67, 68, x, x, x}`, where `x` stands for "indetermined value".

Better version of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++)
{
  arr[i] = s2[i];
}
```

Overall better version:

```
#define MAXLINE 1024

char line[MAXLINE];
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
int arr[MAXLINE]; 

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++)
{
  arr[i] = s2[i];
}
```